# Agregar HTML desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, jsp

Estoy realizando una app web  con jsp,  intento desplegar likes de la misma forma que lo hace facebook en una ventana modal, hasta el momento he conseguido pasar  la lista  de quienes han dado like en forma de objeto pero ahora no sé como desplegar  los atributos de ese objeto.

```
<section><!-- Answers -->                                
   <div class="row"> <!-- respuestas publicadas -->                                    
      <h2>Answers </h2>                    
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%                     
          ArrayList<Answer> Respuestas=DB.MostrarRespuestas(idPregunta); //lista de respuestas a la pregunta
          ArrayList<Usuario> likes; //Almacena la lista de las personas a quienes les gusta una respuesta especifica                            
          for(int i=0;i<Respuestas.size();i++) //ciclo para colocar todas las respuestas
          {
            out.println("<div class=row>");//Div general

             out.println("<h5>"+Respuestas.get(i).getUser()+" answered :</h5>");//usuario que publico la respuesta
             out.println("<p>Date: "+Respuestas.get(i).getFecha()+"</p>");// fecha en que la publico

              out.println("<div class=col-md-1>");//Div foto de usuario
               out.println("<a href='../user/user.jsp?wiw="+Respuestas.get(i).getWiw()+"'><img src='../img/user/"+Respuestas.get(i).getWiw()+".png' class='img-circle img-responsive'></a>");//Imagen del usuario
              out.println("</div>");//Cierra Div foto de usuario

              out.println("<div class=col-md-1>");//Div Like

               out.println("<form  action='../Like' method='post'>");//formulario  like
                 likes=DB.Usuarios_Liked(Respuestas.get(i).getIdAnswer());//Obtiene la lista de las personas a quienes les gusta la respuesta
                 String habilitar="";//habilita o deshabilita el boton

                 for(int j=0;j<likes.size();j++)//recorre toda la lista
                    if(likes.get(j).getWiw().equals(user.getWiw()))//si el usaurio que accedio aparece en la lista
                      habilitar="disabled"; //bloquea el boton like

                out.println("<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' disable='true' "+habilitar+" >");//boton de like                                                    
                  out.println("<center><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up' aria-hidden='true'></i>  Like "+likes.size()+"<center>");//numero de likes que tiene la respuesta                                                    
                out.println("</button>");



                 out.println("<input type='hidden' name='idAnswer' value="+Respuestas.get(i).getIdAnswer()+">");//id de la respuesta a l que se le dio like (oculto)
                 out.println("<input type='hidden' name='wiw' value="+user.getWiw()+">");//wiw del usuario que le dio like(oculto)
                 out.println("<center><a href='#' data-id="+Respuestas.get(i)+" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' >ver</a></center>");//despliega la lista de personas a quienes les gusta la respuesta
                out.println("<input type='hidden' name='idQuestion' value="+idPregunta+">");//id de la pregunta a la que pertenece la respueta (oculto)
                out.println("</form>");//Cierra formulario  like
              out.println("</div>");// Cierra Div Like


              out.println("<div class=col-md-10>");//Div texto respuesta
                out.println("<textarea style='margin-bottom:50px' class='form-control' readonly='true'>");                                    
                                        out.println(Respuestas.get(i).getText());
                out.println("</textarea>");                                    
                out.println("</div>");//Cierra Div texto respuesta

               out.println("</div>");//Cierra Div general                                                                                               


         }
            %>

      </div><!-- cierra col-md-12 -->
     </div><!-- cierra respuestas publicadas -->                            
</section><!-- cierra Answers -->
```

Utilizo una función de javaScript para poder pasar  valores al modal

```
<script>
        //Funcion para enviar la lista de likes al modal           

        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {    
            var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data().id;            
            $(e.currentTarget).find('#lista').val(id);            
            });
        });                
    </script>
```

ya tengo el objeto en la ventana modal pero  ahora no puedo mostrar sus  atributos en el modal.

Answer (score 1):

lo que estas pasando al modal son solamente los id, prueba poniendo esta funcion en el onclick:

```
  $('element_class').on('click',function (e, value, row) {

        modal.data('id', row.id);

    for (var name in row) {
        modal.find('input[name="' + name + '"]').val(row[name]);
    }
    modal.modal('show');          
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

proba utilizando el metodo append():

```
 $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {    
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data().id;            
        var data = $(e.currentTarget).find('#lista').val(id);
        $(this).append('<div>'+data+'</div>'); 
 });
```

El metodo append() se encarga de insertar html.
Acá te dejo la documentación de append: http://api.jquery.com/append/